# $.find method checking empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a pagination `<div>`. In that For selected page i have given `selectedPage` class to it.
I am creating pagination DOM from my server side. All code is dynamic.

Now i want find selected Page number , for that i am doing as follows

```
$( "#paginatDiv" ).find( ".selectedPage" )
```

I want to trigger onClick event for this element , so i am doing as follows

```
 $( "#paginatDiv" ).find( ".selectedPage" ).click();
```

`<div id="paginatDiv">` this `<div>` for pagination per page 10 records.
Now my problem is when i have less than 10 records in table i am not showing this
`<div id="paginatDiv">`.

i know i can check this div exists or not but i want know i can check something as follows

```
if($( "#paginatDiv" ).find( ".selectedPage" ).length == 0){
  // not exist
}else{
  //  exist
}
```

My concern is if `<div id="paginatDiv">` is not in HTML page then what happen for

```
$( "#paginatDiv" ).find( ".selectedPage" ).length
```

it will give error ?

Comment: I truly don't understand your question. very unclear

Comment: yes i think i could not explain well here

Answer (score 4):

Just like what you've described, you can check if the length of `.selectedPage` inside `#paginatDiv` is less than `10` than hide `#paginatDiv` respectively:

```
if($( "#paginatDiv" ).find( ".selectedPage" ).length < 10){
    $('#paginatDiv').hide();
} else {
    //  exist
}
```

or you can shorten your selector to:

```
if($("#paginatDiv .selectedPage").length < 10){
    $('#paginatDiv').hide();
} else {
    //  exist
}
```

Comment: if there is no element exist then lenght will 0 ??

Comment: From the question it really sounds like there's only ever going to be at most one element with `.selectedPage`, since it indicates the selected page. They also said they don't show (I'm not sure if it still exists in the page's HTML, that isn't clear) if there are less than ten **records**, which isn't the same as a page.

Comment: @user3243855 Yes, it will be 0. The code above will hide the `#paginatDiv` if number of `.selectedPage` inside `#paginatDiv` are less than `10`.

Answer (score 4):

check whether the length is less than 10

```
if ($("#paginatDiv .selectedPage").length > 9) {
    // fire as it is shown
} else {
    // don't fire
}
```

Comment: `$("#paginatDiv .selectedPage")` I prefer